# Como poner un value a sumernote con el fin de editarlo en la base de datos

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, text

necesito editar un texto que se encuentra en mysql, para esto quiero ponerlo en summernote como un value, he probado algunas cosas pero ninguna me ha funcionado. En resumidas cuentas mi pregunta es: Como puedo poner un texto desde mysql en el textarea de summernote?

En mi vista blade tengo el siguiente script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            
            $('.summernote').summernote(
                {
                    disableDragAndDrop: true,
                    height: 300,                 // set editor height
                    minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
                    maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
                    lang: 'es-CO',
                    toolbar: [
                        // [groupName, [list of button]]
                        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                        ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
                        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                        ['color', ['color']],
                        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                        ['picture', ['picture']],
                        ['table', ['table']],
                        ['undo' , ['undo']],
                        ['redo' , ['redo']]
                    ],
                }

            );
        });
    </script>
```

y el siguiente form

```html
<form id="formulario" method="post" action="/">
            @csrf            

            <textarea class="summernote" name="hechos" id="hechos" value="dasfsdfs" required></textarea>
            

            <textarea class="summernote" name="pruebas" id="pruebas" required></textarea>
            

            <textarea class="summernote" name="anexos" id="anexos"></textarea>

            <div class="container text-center separador-boton">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success text-center" type="submit">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Lo que se me ocurrió en primera instancia era poner le un value al textarea con la llamada al objeto de la base de datos que contiene el texto correspondiente, pero por alguna razón se me ha hecho muy difícil. Agradezco cualquier información al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de investigar un poco más encontre la solución:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.summernote').summernote(
                $('.summernote').eq(0).html('{{$texto[0]->hechos}}'),
                $('.summernote').eq(1).html('{{$texto[0]->pruebas}}'),
                $('.summernote').eq(2).html('{{$texto[0]->anexos}}'),
                {
                    disableDragAndDrop: true,
                    height: 300,                 // set editor height
                    minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
                    maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
                    lang: 'es-CO',
                    toolbar: [
                        // [groupName, [list of button]]
                        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                        ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
                        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                        ['color', ['color']],
                        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                        ['picture', ['picture']],
                        ['undo' , ['undo']],
                        ['redo' , ['redo']]
                    ],
                }
            );

        });
    </script>
```

De esta forma logré traer los textos que necesitaba desde la DB y mostrarlos en el textarea para que dean editados y enviados nuevamente.